# How to do math in latex?

Tags: macros

I am in need of a command to convert Gregorian calendar year to Jalali calendar year, the conversion equation is simple and is as below:

[image]

I want to create a command to convert a Gregorian year# to Jalali year# automatically, how can I do this?

Comment: Are there counters defined for these calendars? In which packages?

Comment: What do you mean? I simply want to have a command to the following: `cnvt{2016}` and the result should `1395` which is `1395=2016-621`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If no counters should be used, a `\the\numexpr#1-621` (in a macro) is perhaps the easiest way of doing integer math and it is expandable if the result should be used in further calculations:

`\numexpr#1-621` uses the first argument and subtracts `621` from this value (hopefully it is an integer).

`\the\numexpr...` guarantees expandability of this code.

`\numexpr` requires `e-TeX` features, but this should be no limitation after almost 20 years of having those `e-TeX` extensions...)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\cnvt}[1]{\the\numexpr#1-621\relax}

\begin{document}
\cnvt{2016}

\edef\cnvtresult{\cnvt{2016}}% Store the result if precisely this value is needed
\cnvtresult

\end{document}
```

Both times `1395` is printed.

Update -- a counter based version is added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{jalaliyear}
\newcommand*{\cnvt}[1]{\the\numexpr#1-621\relax}

\newcommand{\cnvtother}[1]{%
  \setcounter{jalaliyear}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{jalaliyear}{-621}%
}
\newcounter{loopcntr}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
Version without counter: \cnvt{2016}

\edef\cnvtresult{\cnvt{2016}}
And once again: \cnvtresult

\cnvtother{2016}Now the counter version: the jalali year corresponding to 2016 is \thejalaliyear%

Now a nice loop -- code golfing ;-)

\begin{multicols}{6}
\tiny
\setcounter{loopcntr}{620}
\loop\ifnum \value{loopcntr} < 2017\relax
\stepcounter{loopcntr}%
\theloopcntr\hfill\cnvt{\value{loopcntr}}

\repeat
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dariush: You're welcome. Happy Texing!

Comment: A `\relax` would come in handy.

Comment: @Manuel: Done ....

Comment: No, sorry, I meant `\newcommand*\cnvt[1]{\the\numexpr#1-621\relax}`. If you follow `\cnvt{2016}` by some spaces, and numbers, or `-` or `(` it may give unexpected results without the `\relax`.